# How to convert a Gradle project's dependencies into a local maven repository?

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, packaging

I am building a Java SDK that can be used to work on my app.

When I run `./gradlew :my-sdk-library:dependencies` I get my transitive tree of deps.

All my customers refuse to access libraries on the internet. And they do not have a local maven proxy either, so I need to supply my sdk jars and the other open source jars too.

So I would like to convert that into a local maven repository so that I can send it to those who cannot access our maven repository that is hosted on Artifactory, nor Maven central.

The naive approach is the make a shaded (shadow) jar containing all the libraries then import it as a `implementation file(path-to-shaded.jar)`. But that is not good because IDEs do not like huge 200MB shaded jar files. And you lose all the dependency management provided by the GAV values.

So I want to produce a local maven repository I can send along with the SDK.

So if this were Maven I would go to a fresh VM, run `mvn install`, then just copy the ~/.m2/repository folder and there you go.

I did find a project https://github.com/sinsongdev/gradle-cash-to-maven-repo which might work to create a local maven repo using the gradle cache, but it is not widely used. I'll give it a try.

Basically I want exactly what https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow does but instead of producing an uber jar, to create a local maven repo.

Is there some option like that in Gradle to create an offline copy of the repo or cache so that developers who are behind strict firewalls can use your SDK?